# Define (pointers to) procedures in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, procedure

I am new to scheme and trying to understand how `define` works when a  procedure is created. More precisely the difference between the following two declarations:

```
(define name (procedure))
(define (name) (procedure))
```

Could someone, pls, hint on how `define` works 'under the hood'? I understand that in the first case `define` creates a pointer to a procedure. The second is a trimmed version of a procedure without arguments `(define (name arg) (procedure))`, but how the pointers `name` and `(name)` differ from each other?

Clearly, the use of `name` depends on how it was defined.

```
> (define proc (+ 1 1))
> proc
2
> (proc)
. . application: not a procedure;


> (define (proc) (+ 1 1))
> proc
#<procedure:proc>
> (proc)
2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these is a pointer in any way, shape, or form.

`define` binds a name to a value in the current environment, and in Scheme, procedures are first-class values.

```
(define name (procedure))
```

defines `name` to be the value that is the result of calling `procedure` right now.

```
(define (name) (procedure))
```

defines `name` to be a procedure that takes no arguments and, when called, returns the result of calling `procedure` with no arguments.
The second form is equivalent to

```
(define name (lambda () (procedure)))
```

Example (from Racket - `current-seconds` is the number of seconds since midnight UTC, January 1, 1970):

```
> (current-seconds)
1462879945
> (define name (current-seconds))
> name
1462879957
```

`name` is a number, not a procedure.

```
> (define (nameproc) (current-seconds))
> nameproc
#<procedure:nameproc>
```

`nameproc` is a procedure, not a number.

```
> (nameproc)
1462879980
> (nameproc)
1462879983
```

As you can see, `nameproc` returns different values each time it's called...

```
> name
1462879957
> name
1462879957
```

... but `name` is an integer and doesn't change.

Answer (score 3):

The `define` form is ‘syntactic sugar’: it's merely a more convenient syntax for something else.  The expression

```
(define (foo x)
  (+ x 1))
```

is by definition equivalent to

```
(define foo
  (lambda (x)
    (+ x 1)))
```

That is, just as `(define bar 1)` sets `bar` equal to the *value* `1`, `(define foo (lambda ...))` defines `foo` as equal to the *value* `(lambda (x) (+ x 1))`, which is a *procedure* (ie, function) that adds 1 to its single argument.

The aha! moment here is realising that in Scheme (and other Lisps) *a procedure is a value*, with the same status as `1` or `"hello"`, which can therefore be assigned to symbols such as `foo`.
The expression `(lambda ...)` evaluates to a value of procedure type.
Get this much straight in your head, and the syntax `(define (foo ...) ...)` should be transparent.

(And don't think of ‘function pointers’ – that's a C notion, which will only confuse things here).

Answer (score 2):

`(define (proc) ...)` is simply syntactic sugar for `(define proc (lambda () ...))`.

If you're familiar with imperative languages, `define` is really an assignement:

```
> (define proc 2)
```

<=> (ish)

```
proc = 2;
```

One thing you can assign to a symbol is a *function*, as follows:

```
> (define proc (lambda (x y) (+ x y)))
> (proc 1 2)
3
```

<=> (ish)

```
>>> proc = lambda x, y: x + y
>>> proc(1, 2)
3
```

Now nothing prevents you from defining the function to take no argument:

```
> (define proc (lambda () (+ 1 1)))
> (proc)
2
```

Which assigns to `proc` the *function* taking no argument, and returning the value of `(+ 1 1)` (i.e. 2). This is *different* from `(define proc (+ 1 1))`, which assigns the value to `proc` directly (and is in fact exactly equivalent to `(define proc 2)`).

Now, what might confuse you is that since writing `lambda` is way too much work, Scheme implementations will usually offer a 'short-hand' version of function definition:

```
> (define (proc <args>) <body>)
<=>
> (define proc (lambda <args> <body>))
```

So `(define (proc) 2)` desugars to `(define proc (lambda () 2))`, while `(define proc 2)` simply assigns `2` to `proc`. The fact that symbols might be bound to values via pointers is an implementation detail which only concern your interpreter, and should be irrelevant to the reasoning.

## TL; DR:

```
(define (func) x)
```

creates a function

```
(define func x)
```

assigns `x` to `func`

Answer (score 0):

`define` is probably the most vague special form in Scheme and it's because it serves different purposes in different scopes and with different first argument. Here goes:

**Difference between symbol and list first argument**

The basic usage of `define` is:

```
(define var <expression>)
```

It defines the variablel `var` with the result of the expression `<expression>`.

Since Scheme is a LISP1 procedures (also known as function in some other languages) are created with a evaluated lambda form eg. `(lambda argument-list . body)` you can give a procedure a name by assigning it with `define`:

```
(define add1 (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)))
```

For naming procedures `define` has a a special syntax where the `define` and `lambda` forms are mashed together. You can write `add1` as:

```
(define (add1 n) (+ 1 n))
```

It means exactly the same and some books keep from exposing this last version to the user since it's more confusing to have two ways to do it, especially if you want a procedure to return a procedure.

**Top level or lexical scope**

When top level the value are assigned to global scope. That means all procedures will be able to access it unless the variable is redefined  at a local scope looking at the code from the use and up to top level.

If the `define` happens in a procedure or a syntax sugar of a procedure (`let`, `let*`, `letrec`, `rec`, `lambda`) then the form is identical to a `letrec` at the top of the procedure and it only lives within that procedure and nested procedure. The second the code in the letrec is finished running the bindings disappear:

```
(define (test n)
  (define v (* 2 n))
  (define (add1 n) (+ 1 n))

  (add1 v))
```

This is the same as:

```
(define test 
  (lambda (n)
    (letrec ((v (* 2 n))
             (add1 (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)))
      (add1 v))))
```

A letrec is just a fancy `let`

```
(define test 
  (lambda (n)
    (let ((v 'undefined) (add1 'undefined))
      (let ((v1 (* 2 n))
            (v2 (lambda (n) (+ 1 n))))
        (set! v v1)
        (set! add1 v2))
      (add1 v))))
```

And of course `let` is just an `lambda` that is immediately applied:

```
(define test 
  (lambda (n)
    ((lambda  (v add1)
       ((lambda (v1 v2)
          (set! v v1)
          (set! add1 v2)) (* 2 n) (lambda (n) (+ 1 n)))

       (add1 v) ; can access n, v, and add1 but not v1, and v2 
       'undefined 'undefined)))
```

`define` only makes bindings between names and values where values usually means address to an object (aka pointers). The same name can have different bindings in different scopes so the same variable name doesn't always point to the same object. Here's an example:

```
(define lst '(1 2 3 4 5))
(define (last x)
  (define lst (cdr x))
  (if (null? lst)
      (car lst)
      (last lst)))

(last lst) ; ==> 5
```

Here the top level `lst` is always `'(1 2 3 4 5)` while the `lst` in the procedure is always one of the sub lists of the argument `x`. They exist at the same time with the same name but both point to different values. In the body the global is not accessible since it's shadowed by the local binding with the same name.